# Access uneven high leveled associative array in php

Tags: php, associative-array

I have nested associative array with more than 4 levels. Some values goes to all 4 levels while some ends on first level. Now how do I access all values from php.

For 2 levels array I can just:

```
foreach($options as $o){
    foreach($m as $check){
        if(isset($check[$o])) echo $check[$o];
    }
}
```

to check if a value is set and then use it.
But how do I do this for the array having unknown depth or a lot of levels with uneven level.

Comment: 'Recursion' is your keyword. (But you can also have a loop with a variable containing the current array.)

Comment: You should look at the [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function as so:

```
<?php
    function getSetValues($array, $searchKeys) {
        $values = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $values = array_merge($values, getSetValues($value, $searchKeys));
            } else if (in_array($key, $searchKeys)) {
                $values[] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $values;
    }

    $values = getSetValues(array(
        'foo' => array(
            'bar' => 123,
            'rab' => array(
                'oof' => 'abc'
            ),
            'oof' => 'cba'
        ),
        'oof' => 912
    ), array('bar', 'oof')); //Search for keys called 'bar' or 'oof'

    print_r($values);

?>
```

Which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123 (because the key is 'bar')
    [1] => abc (because the key is 'oof')
    [2] => cba (because the key is 'oof')
    [3] => 912 (because the key is 'oof')
)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/47TVK3w7)

Answer (score 1):

It depends by what you mean with 'access'. If you just want to print out the values you could use a recursive function like this:

```
function crawlArray($myArray, $depth=0) {
  foreach ($myArray as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v)) {
      crawlArray($v, ++$depth);
    } else {
      echo $v;
    }
  }
}

crawlArray($options);
```